# MySQL query for specific year and region

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I try to make a query, where I can see the netamount of sales for the
US and rest of the World for the years 2007 and 2008 in the database along with all subtotals as well as the grand total.(It's to mention, that US and World are regions, which are already coded in the database)

My query as far:

```
SELECT country regionname, sum(custamot)Totsales 
FROM( select o.customerid, sum(netamount) custamot, c.country
FROM orders o join customers c
on o.customerid = c.customerid
where country like 'US' 
group by c.customerid ) iv;
```

This query just tells me the totsales for US(without a year as you can see). 
I tried the query without the part:

```
where country like 'US'
```

but the result is the same. I can't find a query where it shows me the US and the World for a specific year...

Any idea would be helpful

gratefully,
JOP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a `group by` clause on the outside:

```
SELECT country as regionname, sum(custamot) as Totsales 
FROM (select o.customerid, sum(netamount) custamot, c.country
      FROM orders o join
           customers c
           on o.customerid = c.customerid
      group by c.customerid
     ) iv
group by country;
```

Actually, you don't need the subquery:

```
select country as regionname, sum(netamount) as Totsales
FROM orders o join
     customers c
     on o.customerid = c.customerid
group by country;
```

And to get the total in the same query use `with rollup`:

```
select country as regionname, sum(netamount) as Totsales
FROM orders o join
     customers c
     on o.customerid = c.customerid
group by country with rollup;
```

And finally, to add the year, either use a `where` clause or try this:

```
select year(orderdate) as yr, country as regionname, sum(netamount) as Totsales
FROM orders o join
     customers c
     on o.customerid = c.customerid
group by year(orderdate), country with rollup;
```

And to separate US and ROW:

```
select year(orderdate) as yr,
       (case when country = 'US' then 'US' else 'ROW' end) as region,
       sum(netamount) as TotSales
FROM orders o join
     customers c
     on o.customerid = c.customerid
group by year(orderdate),  (case when country = 'US' then 'US' else 'ROW' end) with rollup;
```

Comment: wow thanks. Looks perfect. I just put the where clause in again so i can see the relevant fields. like this:    where country like 'US'
Now my other problem is how to sum up "the rest of the World", when i just try: where country like 'World' i get an empty table. Still i try to get a result table, where i can see 4 lines:(2x US(2007 and 2008) and 2x World(2007/2008) the year part is not the problem anymore just the World part, any idea  there?

Comment: That is just PERFECT. Exactly how i tried to do it. I also got the hint from a friend who told me that i would need a case. Thanks alot "again" :)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
SELECT country as regionname, sum(custamot)Totsales 
FROM( select o.customerid, sum(netamount) custamot, c.country
      FROM orders o join customers c
       on o.customerid = c.customerid
      where left(my_date,4) between 2007 and 2008
      group by c.customerid ) iv
group by country
```

Saludos ;)

Answer (score 0):

To get the results for a certain year, assuming you have a date field,

```
where YourDateField >= {d '2007-01-01'}
and YourDateField < {d '2008-01-01'}
```